# Implementation of insertion sort

Tags: c

Here's my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void insert(int member,int arr[],int size)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(member<arr[i])
        {

            for( j=0;j<size-i;j++)
            {
                arr[size]=arr[size-1];
        }
         arr[i]=member;
         break;
         }
    }    
}
void insertsort(int arr[],int size)
{
    int newsize=1,member;
    for(newsize=1;newsize<size;newsize++)
    {
    member=arr[newsize];
    insert(member,arr,newsize);
    }
}
void main()
{
    int arr[100];
    int size,i;
    printf("enter the size");
    scanf("%d",&size);
    printf("enter numbers");
    for( i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    insertsort(arr,size);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    printf("\n %d",arr[i]);
}
```

I dont know what the problem is but on entering

Number of elements : 5;

INPUT NUMBERS 45 23 87 345 12

OUTPUT 12 45 87 345 345.

Can someone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Looks like an off-by-one problem.

Comment: @Delan Azabani  what is that?

Comment: Please indent your code. It'll be that much easier to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Instead of looking for the exact problem in this implementation, you should rewrite it.  What you have now is three nested loops: an outer loop in `insertsort` calling an inner function with its own doubly-nested loops.  That's excessive.  You only need two loops.

Comment: @Ray Toal  will it make any difference.. i can take the third loop from the inside and do it the other way round i.e when member > arr[i] dont do anything else shift..
i guess the complexity will be the same.Since what i am doing is also the same. if the member < arr[i] then shift.. and once the shifting is done(which will be done in both the cases) i am breaking out of the loop!

Comment: I see what you are saying, @Karan, you are using the outer loop in `insert` to try to find the right position to start sifting.  But you should already have that position in the first loop (in `insertsort`).  In general, writing unnecessary code increases the chances for errors and makes the code harder to read and debug.  I was simply suggesting to trim the code down so it would be easier to locate your error.

Comment: what i have in insert sort is the new sizes of array.. i.e the dividing part of my algo.. then in insert i find the right position , where to start shifting in the first loop.. and the second loop just executes once. when the position is found..

Comment: Yes, I know the approach, and it isn't really wrong.  But when you strip the code down and focus on what you've written, you'll see what is inside the `j` loop.  Or, what is _not_ inside the `j`-loop.  Namely a `j`. :-)

Comment: yeah.. that was the correction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you inset function, change `arr[size]=arr[size-1];` to `arr[size-j]=arr[size-j-1];`.

When you do the insertion, I guess you wanted to shift all the numbers after the insertion point 1 step right, but instead you only shifted the right most one.

```
void insert(int member,int arr[],int size)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(member<arr[i])
        {
            for( j=0;j<size-i;j++)
            {
                arr[size-j]=arr[size-j-1];
            }
            arr[i]=member;
            break;
         }
    }     
}
```

Comment: You can replace the loop by `memmove(&arr[i], &arr[i+1], (size-i+1)*sizeof arr[0]);`. It's often faster and it makes the code clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(i=1; i<N; i++)
    {
        Temp = A[i];
        j = i-1;
        while(Temp<A[j] && j>=0)
        {
            A[j+1] = A[j];
            j = j-1;
        }
        A[j+1] = Temp;
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps some more elaboration would make this answer better.

Comment: @zzzz how would this help me? when insert will be called the size=newsize=0; hence no loop will be executed, and it will return back..

Comment: that is your insertion sort code.. you just need that.. get rid of you insert etc..

Comment: The tests in the inner while loop should be changed to `while(j>=0 && Temp<A[j])` to avoid a subscript out-of-bounds bug.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for insertion sort:

```
int InsertionSort()
{
    int max;
    int *numarray = 0;
int i,j,k,temp;

printf("\nProgram for Ascending order of Numeric Values using INSERTION SORT");
    printf("\n\nEnter the total number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &max);   

    numarray = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * max);

    for(i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter [%d] element: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &numarray[i]);
    }

    printf("Before Sorting   : ");
    for(k = 0; k < max; k++)
        printf("%d ", numarray[k])
    printf("\n");

    for(i = 1; i < max; i++)
    {
        j = i;
        while(j > 0)
        {
            if(numarray[j-1] > numarray[j])
            {
                temp = numarray[j - 1];
                numarray[j - 1] = numarray[j];
                numarray[j] = temp;
                j--;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        printf("After iteration %d ": ", i);
        for(k = 0; k < max; k++)
            printf("%d ", numarray[k] );
        printf("/*** %d numbers from the begining of the array are input and they are sorted ***/\n", i + 1);
    }

    printf("\n\nThe numbers in ascending orders are given below:\n\n");
    for(i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        printf("Sorted [%d] element: %d\n",i + 1, numarray[i]);
    }

    free(numarray);
    return 0;
}
```

The output would be

Program for Ascending order of Numeric Values using INSERTION SORT

Enter the total number of elements: 8

Enter [1] element: 80

Enter [2] element: 60

Enter [3] element: 40

Enter [4] element: 20

Enter [5] element: 10

Enter [6] element: 30

Enter [7] element: 50

Enter [8] element: 70

The numbers in ascending orders are given below:

Sorted [1] element: 10

Sorted [2] element: 20

Sorted [3] element: 30

Sorted [4] element: 40

Sorted [5] element: 50

Sorted [6] element: 60

Sorted [7] element: 70

Sorted [8] element: 80

Answer (score 0):

Here is the insertion sort in C#. You can easily convert it into C or C++

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] set = new[] { 5, 3, 2, 9, 6, 1, 7, 2 };
        int[] result = InsertionSort(set);
    }

    static int[]  InsertionSort(int[] list) {
        if (list.Length < 2) {
            return list;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j > 0 && list[j - 1] > list[j]; j--) {
                int temp = list[j - 1];
                list[j - 1] = list[j];
                list[j] = temp;
            }  
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A is an array with unsorted elements.. 
The idea is very similar to how you sort cards in your hand in a typical card game. 
You pick up first card. You then pick second card and so on.. and compare backwards until you find a card whose value is  greater than the current card. You then insert current card in this location effectively shifting all cards to right as you move backward. After this loop, all elements in your hand are sorted.
I have a more detailed description at http://www.worldkosh.com/2016/12/22/insertion-sort/

The article is inspired from Cormen, Thomas H.; Leiserson, Charles E.; Rivest, Ronald L.; Stein, Clifford (2001) [1990]. Introduction to Algorithms (2nd ed.).

Pseudo Code
Assuming 0 based starting index

```
Insertion_sort(array A) {
    for(int i = 1;i < n; i++) {
        key = A[i];
        for(int j = i-1; j>= 0 and A[j]>key; j--) {
            A[j +1] = A[j];
        }
        A[j+1] = key;       
    }  
}
```